# $event.stopPropogation is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a scenario where when i click on input box which is inside a div the div functionality is getting effected.

Suppose the div is selected and is red in color,when i click on the input box which is inside the selected div, the div is turning unselected(grey color).

For this i have used $event.stopPropogation on input box which isn't working

html

```
<body>
  <div class="container" ng-controller="BaseController">
      <div class="row" ng-click="selectedDiv=!selectedDiv" ng-class="{'colorDiv':selectedDiv}">
          <input placeholder="enter text" ng-mousedown="$event.stopPropagation()">
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

controller:

```
 app.controller('BaseController', function($scope) {
  $scope.selectedDiv=true;
});
```

css:

```
 .row{
  width:250px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid grey;
}
.colorDiv{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/GmLv0k3r3pn2LYUGd025?p=preview)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you not using `ng-click` instead of `ng-mousedown`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to explicitly stop click event propagation of `input` box to bubble up, for the same you could use `ng-click` instead of `ng-mousedown`(mousedown will only fire when hover over on `input` box).

```
ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();"
```

[**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/GmLv0k3r3pn2LYUGd025?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You're current setup starts out in the selected state, and when you click the div it becomes the unselected state.

```
app.controller('BaseController', function($scope) {
    $scope.selectedDiv=false;
});
```

Change the starting value of `$scope.selectedDiv = false;`